# pandas DataFrame float column gets converted to object after values in a different column are renamed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that I was doing some clean up on and for some reason the column I didn't touch at all got switch from type float to object. The column has no Nan values just numbers and has not been messed with at all.

```
data = pd.read_csv(path, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=['c_id', 'c_name', 'org_name', 'product', 'amount', 'date', 'product_type', 'payment_type'])

mask = data['c_name'] == data['org_name']
data['c_type'] = np.where(mask, 'Org', 'Ind')
data.loc[data['product_type'] == 'product'] = 'Product'
```

If I print out column types before the last line the **amount column** is a float but if I do the same after the last line then the amount column type is changed to object.

The last line is just there to correct a label issue so why would it effect the type of other columns?

I know I can change the type for column manually but I am just trying to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the entire row to the string `product` using your `loc` statement, so in fact, `amount` does get modified. Instead, just change the value in the column `'product_type'`:

```
data.loc[data['product_type'] == 'product', 'product_type'] = 'Product'
```

And your `amount` column will be unchanged.

Another way to do this would be to use `replace`:

```
data.replace({'product_type':{'product':'Product'}}, inplace=True)
# or:
data['product_type'] = data['product_type'].replace('product', 'Product')
```